# Anonymize comments after one year

Tags: comments, users

How can i anonymize any comment after a certain time? 
Is there a way to do this?
It's for data protection.

Comment: Do you mean just on the front-end **or** do you want to clear all the user input data (like name/email etc) on the backend as well? As in, the stored data of the comment...

Comment: I mean the second one. I want to overwrite the whole user related data.

Comment: create an anonymous User. Write a Plug-in using WordPress cron to check comments of all users for creation date + 1year. if that applies move comments to user anonymous

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a ready to use solution. Howeder I think is not to heavy to build a custom plugin, that do that.

1. Update the comment data, use [`wp_update_comment()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_comment).
2. For anonymize the IP you can use [`wp_privacy_anonymize_ip()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43545) *(currently not in core, open as ticket)*.
3. Use the wp cron to run this after 6 months and build a comparison with the comment date to anonymize the data of the comment.

Alternative to the wp function to anonymize the IP helps this small function, only an small idea.

```
function fb_cut_ip( $ip, $cut_end = true )
{
    return str_replace(
        ( $cut_end ? strrchr( $ip, ':' ) : strstr( $ip, ':' ) ),
        '',
        $ip
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help.

Here is my final solution:
It's a PHP-snippet that i paste into a wp cron job plugin.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_privacy_anonymize_comments' );
function wp_privacy_anonymize_comments() {
  $expiry_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 years"));
  $args = array(
    // args here
 );

// The Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$meta_values = $comments_query->query( $args );

foreach($meta_values as $meta_value) :
    $current_comment_ID =   $meta_value->comment_ID;
    $current_comment_date = $meta_value->comment_date;

    if ($current_comment_date < $expiry_date) {
        //Override Userdata #anonymer-Bär
        $update_comment = array(
            'comment_ID'    => $current_comment_ID,
            'comment_author'=> 'Anonym ' . $current_comment_ID,
            'comment_author_email' => 'anonym@web.de',
            'comment_author_url' => ''
        );
        wp_update_comment($update_comment);
    }
endforeach;
}
```

Thank you all :)
Kind regards, Kathi